# Redmine / ChiliProject - Restrict login by ip address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins, chiliproject

I would like to restrict access to certain users of a redmine/chiliproject install as long as they are coming from a certain ip address or a certain range of ip addresses.

Is there a plugin for this or is there an easy (ie quick simple) way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "restrict access" To fully block people, you can configure your frontend webserver. For special actions that alter default ChiliProject / Redmine behavior you'd need a plugin. You'd also need to make sure that the Ruby instance sees the actual remote IP (e.g. via X-Forwarded-For)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an apache server to serve the static files and proxy requests to redmine, you could use `mod_authz_host` of apache and add some rules to the configuration of your site. For example:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 64.34.119.12
```

More example and documentation on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html*